# External login facebok mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to add external facebook login to my Asp.net mvc application that work fine when I run on localhost but when I upload to IIS server then

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

always return null although the application open facebook dialoge and got permissions to my face app

```
using System;
using MySystem.IdentityModels;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;
namespace MySystem
{
public partial class Startup
{
     public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Users/login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
         app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
        // Facebook
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
                appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                appSecret: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    } 
   }
}
```

what is the error ?

Comment: There must be an error that is being returned. I would recommend checking the redirect URI and adding the uri of IIS into your Facebook App.

Comment: redirect_url in facebook link is domainname.com with http  although I added redirect_url into facebook App secure domainname.com with https . 
I don not know why that